# ALTER SWITCH fails when cdc is turned on

Tags: sql-server, cdc, sql-server-2019

I have SQL server 2019 CU8. change data capture (CDC) is turned on for the DB.
Strange, but this query fails

```
ALTER TABLE tblTemp
SWITCH PARTITION $partition.dateRangepfDay(@datefor) TO tblM PARTITION $partition.dateRangepfDay(@datefor)
```

error is

```
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000)
```

Small investigation went to DB new DATABASE trigger (that was created after CDC) `tr_MScdc_ddl_event`

Somehow I know that query works:

```
ALTER TABLE tblTemp
SWITCH PARTITION $partition.dateRangepfDay('2020-12-16') TO tblM PARTITION $partition.dateRangepfDay('2020-12-16')
```

(switch variable to text value)

Does anybody know why it is happen and why behavior is different?

Comment: No, but that's interesting that it works with static values! Is there any clue in the body of the trigger you mention?

Comment: well, `tr_MScdc_ddl_event` calls `sys.sp_MScdc_ddl_event` that calls `sys.sp_cdc_ddl_event_internal`. That's it (